# Differnece between the IE6 and IE8 for Asp.net MVC

Tags: internet-explorer

I am working on my Office PC I dont have, I dont not have Admin rights to download IE8 in my PC..currently I am working in asp.net mvc application with IE6 Browser..some of the things are not working in IE6 for my application, can any body explain me what is the Differnce between IE6 and IE8 for web application,

is there any chance that if the web pages are not showing correctly in IE6 it wil show in IE8?

Ex: I used Microsoft Charting Controls to dispaly Pie chart for my applciation. the pie chart displaying in Firefox but not in IE6

Ex: some of the checkbox check events not working in IE6 but its working with Firefox.

what is the good way to test wihout instaling IE8 on my PC? is there any tools are there?

any documents to refer these stuff..?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be blunt, ask your IT department why you are still running IE6, it is at the end of it's support lifetime and is unsecure as hell.
In other words, upgrade...

Comment: This is not the Exact answer i am looking for, the Upgrading takes place I know.. but in my question I am asking what is the Differnce IE6 and IE8

thanks for your time Colin..

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft celebrates death of IE6 so ask for change your browser and enjoy.